# I want to update username and password securely in sqlite database

Tags: android

I had tried using SQLCipher etc.., But still able to hack my database. I want to insert, update securely. Any help or suggestions it could be better.Thank you

Please check what I have written code for insert and update its normal database code. I want to do secure the same structure code

```
 public class SqlDatabaseAdapter  {
            SqlHelper helper;
            public SqlDatabaseAdapter(Context context)
            {
                helper=new SqlHelper(context);
            }
            public long insertData(String email,String password)
            {
                SQLiteDatabase db=helper.getWritableDatabase();
                ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
                cv.put(SqlHelper.NAME,email);
                cv.put(SqlHelper.PASSWORD,password);
                long id=db.insert(SqlHelper.TABLE_NAME,null,cv);
                return id;
            }


        public int updateData(String oldName,String newName)
        {
            SQLiteDatabase db=helper.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
            cv.put(SqlHelper.NAME, newName);
            int upade=db.update(SqlHelper.TABLE_NAME,cv,SqlHelper.NAME+"=?",new String[]{oldName});
            return upade;

        }
        }
```

Comment: Please show, database structure, sample input and desired result. I.e. get as close to a [mcve] as you can. The SQLite command line tool offers a convenient way for doing so, just use `.dump` on an appropriatly tailored toy-database. Also it would be helpful if you state whether you can achieve your goal directly from the commandline tool on that toydatabase.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 public int updateData(String oldName,String newName)
 {
     ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
     values.put(SqlHelper.UID, ID);
     values.put(SqlHelper.NAME,email);
     values.put(SqlHelper.PWD,pwd);

     // updating row
     db.updae(TABLE_NAME, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(user.getId()) });
     return upade;
 }
```

Comment: ...The later answer that doesn't even come close to compiling gets accepted.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static boolean  updateEntry(Student st)
{
    db=dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    // Define the updated row content.
    ContentValues updatedValues = new ContentValues();
    // Assign values for each row.
    updatedValues.put(USER_EMAILID, st.getEmailid());
    updatedValues.put(USER_NAME,st.getName());
    updatedValues.put(USER_CONTACT, st.getMobileno());

    //String where=Database.USER_EMAILID +"=+?";
    //String where="emailid +=?";
    int row_id=db.update(Database.TABLE_NAME,updatedValues, "emailid=?", new String[]{st.getEmailid()});
    Log.d("login", "updated record " +row_id);
    return true;
}
```